# Is there a boat that will take tourists to Iceland from North America?

Tags: adventure, iceland, sea-travel, north-america

I'm certain that the lucky Europeans have a boat that will get them from there to Iceland.  Is there a way for tourists to get from the US or Canada to Iceland?

Comment: What kind of a boat are you looking for? Like a cruise or just a cheap ride there?

Comment: Why wouldn't you fly there? Surely if you have a couple weeks to hang in Iceland you don't want to spend the majority of it on a boat in the middle of the ocean, right?

Comment: Because it would be cool to re-do Bjarni Herjólfsson's and Eric the Red's trips. And depending on the boat, travel by boat can be more pleasant than flying.

Comment: I added the [tag:adventure] tag based on your reason for not wanting to fly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This one](http://www.cruisecompete.com/itins/maasdam_cruises_jafcgei.html) leaves from Boston and makes a couple of stops in Iceland, one of which is at Heimaey where they famously [fought a volcano and won](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heimaey#Eldfell). It also stops in Greenland and Scotland. [This cruise](http://www.cruisecompete.com/itins/ocean_princess_cijb.html) also visits Iceland.

Both of those cruises only let you off the boat to explore for 8 hours at a time (there are no overnight on-land stays), which I have to say means you will not really see much of Iceland. An alternative is to fly direct to Iceland from Boston, Minneapolis/St. Paul, New York JFK, Orlando Sanford, Seattle or Washington D.C with [Icelandair](http://icelandair.com/)

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell, there are no commercial passenger services, however you may be able to hitch a ride on a cargo vessel, as [this traveller](http://www.gapyear.com/boards/index.php?op=vt&c=4&f=6&t=493099) seems to have done.

Comment: Hi, I know it's a long time ago that you posted the answer, but unfortunately the link is dead. Would you be able to update your answer with a correct link (maybe via an [archiving](https://archive.org/) or [webcaching](http://brutegorilla.com/how-to-use-google-webcache/) service)? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Get in touch with [Adventure Canada](http://www.adventurecanada.com/). They have trips by boat that leave from Canada, and trips that involve Iceland, and it's possible they have trips that do both.

Answer (score 6):

[There is a Princess Cruise in the fall that will take you FROM Iceland and Greenland to New York, North America.](http://www.princess.com/find/searchResults.do?time=208&trade=E&ship=EP&duration=3&port=NYC&date=&order=&filterBy=&tourdur=&resType=C&bID=PCPB&pageOffset=)

But it starts in Europe (Copenhagen). So you have at least one leg of the trip to your satisfaction.